# APIM manager API policy creation using azuredevops pipeline

Tags: bash, azure-devops, azure-api-management, azure-cli, azure-pipelines-yaml

Looking for a way to automate the custom policy creation across the scope of api and operations idempoently in Azure API manager.

The pipeline input is as below

```
stages:
  - template: api-ops-pipeline.yaml
    parameters:
      policyList:
      - name: rate_limit_ip
        scope: api
        apiname: test-policy, test2-policy

      - name: IPfilter
        scope: operation
        ipAddressesFrom: xxxxx
        ipAddressesTo: xxxxxxx
        operationname: getxxx, getyy, getzz
```

policy.xml template

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
         $(rate-limit-by_ip)
         $(rate-limit-by_subkey)
         $(rate-limit-by_DevID)
         $(rate-limit-by_ip)+$(rate-limit-by_DevID)
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
         $(rate-limit-by-ip_error)
         $(rate-limit-by_DevID_error)
         
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

As a first task, we have to create the custom initial_policy.xml file in different scenarios as per the policy list provided by the app team and need to generate it in accordance with the scope of the policy (might be specific to api or might be specifically to a single operation in it or multiple operation in it)

We may have the different combination as below and, when the scope is only to operations, it should first check whether the same policy is applied in its parent api or APIM instance level itself.

Combinations

- rate-limit-by_ip
- rate-limit-by_subkey
- rate-limit-by_DevID
- rate-limit-by_ip+ rate-limit-by_DevID
- Or any custom combination with on error properties as well

Once the above step is completed, in the above created custom  initial_policy.xml  , the users inputs parameters are replaced (threshold, time etc..) and final_policy.xml will be created.

Then , finally it can be applied to the scope given, (might be to api/apis or operation/operations)

The pipeline template  drafyed as below.

```
  jobs:
  - job: api
    displayName: 'api policy'
    variables:
    - group: api_policy
    workspace:
      clean: all
    pool:
      name: xxxxxxx
    steps:
    - ${{ each policy in parameters.policyList }}:
      - ${{ if and(eq(policy.name, 'rate_limit_ip'), eq(policy.scope, 'api') ) }}:
        - bash: |      
           apiName=${{ policy.Name }}
           echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=apiName]$apiName" 
           xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
           xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx          
          name: Resolve_variable  

        - task: qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@3
          displayName: 'create initial xml'
          inputs:
            rootDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/policy'
            targetFiles: initial_policy.xml
            tokenPrefix: '${'
            tokenSuffix: '}$'
            enableTelemetry: false
          continueOnError: true

        - task: qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@3
          displayName: 'create final xml'
          inputs:
            rootDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/policy'
            targetFiles: final_policy.xml
            tokenPrefix: '${'
            tokenSuffix: '}$'
            enableTelemetry: false
          continueOnError: true
```

Comment: What is the detailed issue you are facing? From your comment, we do see any error is mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can create and save a template XML in your Azure Git Repos, then fill in with the actual values that are passed from the parameters.

---

If the APIM has some existing policy configuration, you can use the Azure PowerShell cmdlet "[**Get-AzApiManagementPolicy**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/get-azapimanagementpolicy?view=azps-11.1.0)" to get and save the configuration to an XML file. In Azure Pipelines, you can call this cmdlet like as below.

1. Create an ARM service connection ([**Azure Resource Manager service connection**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#azure-resource-manager-service-connection)) to connect to the Azure subscription and resource group where the APIM instance is in.
2. Add an [**`AzurePowerShell@5`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-powershell-v5?view=azure-pipelines) task in your pipeline job like as below.

   ```yaml
   - task: AzurePowerShell@5
     displayName: 'create initial xml'
     inputs:
       azureSubscription: '{ARM service connection}'
       ScriptType: InlineScript
       Inline: |
         $apimContext = New-AzApiManagementContext -ResourceGroupName "{ResourceGroupName}" -ServiceName "{ServiceName}"
         Get-AzApiManagementPolicy -Context $apimContext -ApiId "{ApiId}" -SaveAs "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/policy/initial_policy.xml"
       azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
       pwsh: true
   ```

   - **`{ARM service connection}`**: The name of ARM service connection created above.
   - **`{ResourceGroupName}`**: The name of the resource group. The name is case insensitive.
   - **`{ServiceName}`**: The name of the API Management service.
   - **`{ApiId}`**: API revision identifier.

After generating the XML, you can update it using the new values passed from the parameters.

---

Comment: We are using Linux machines, and cant run the PowerShell comad there. Couldnt fid same commands in azure cli bash commands. Also is there any way to check the exported policy has already the policy is assigned which we are going to apply. ?

Comment: @Vowneee, You can try to parse the exported policy XML file using bash script to get the values of existing policy. With Microsoft Bing or Google, you can easily find some articles and samples about parsing XML files using Bash script on Linux. Then you can compare the values parsed from the XML file with that you are going to apply.