# Azure Api policy export and re-applying with ammendments not working

Tags: bash, shell, azure-pipelines, azure-api-management, azure-pipelines-yaml

We were trying to automate the custom policy creation across the scope of api and operations idempotently in Azure API manager using azuredevops pipeline.

As a first task, we have to create the custom initial_policy.xml file in different scenarios as per the policy list provided by the app team and need to generate it in accordance with the scope of the policy (might be specific to api or might be specifically to a single operation in it or multiple operation in it)

if the same policy is applied in api level .. we have to skip the policy in operation level and only apply it if the policy is not present in the api level.

So we planned to export the policy from API if the scope of the policy is to operation and , same policy file need to be ammended for the operation , only if the policy is not applied in api level.

Tried below bash task to create a xml file from the output, but its not generating in xml formatt.

apiops.sh script

```
#!/bin/bash
api=test-policy
accessTokenResponse=$(az account get-access-token --resource=https://management.core.windows.net/);
#echo "The token response is $accessTokenResponse"
accessToken=$(echo $accessTokenResponse | jq -j '.accessToken');
#echo "The retrieved access token is $accessToken"
authorizationHeader="Bearer $accessToken"
#echo "Generated authorization header $authorizationHeader"
authorizationHeader="Bearer $accessToken"
#echo "Generated authorization header $authorizationHeader"

curl --location 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/xxxxxx/apis/xxx-api/policies?api-version=2022-08-01&=null' \
-H "Authorization: $authorizationHeader"
```

./apiops.sh | jq ".value[0].properties.value"

We may have the different combination as below and,

- rate-limit-by_ip
- rate-limit-by_subkey
- rate-limit-by_DevID
- rate-limit-by_ip+ rate-limit-by_DevID
- Or any custom combination with on error properties as well

Once the above step is completed, in the above created custom  initial_policy.xml  , the users inputs parameters are replaced (threshold, time etc..) and final_policy.xml will be created.

the app pipeline will planned like below.

```
stages:
  - template: api-ops-pipeline.yaml
    parameters:
      policyList:
      - name: rate_limit_ip
        scope: api
        apiname: test-policy, test2-policy

      - name: IPfilter
        scope: operation
        ipAddressesFrom: xxxxx
        ipAddressesTo: xxxxxxx
        operationname: getxxx, getyy, getzz
```

api-ops-pipeline.yaml

```
  jobs:
  - job: api
    displayName: 'api policy'
    variables:
    - group: api_policy
    workspace:
      clean: all
    pool:
      name: xxxxxxx
    steps:
    - ${{ each policy in parameters.policyList }}:
      - ${{ if and(eq(policy.name, 'rate_limit_ip'), eq(policy.scope, 'operation') ) }}:
        - bash: |      
           apiName=${{ policy.Name }}
           echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=apiName]$apiName" 
           xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
           xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx          
          name: Resolve_variable  

        - task: qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@3
          displayName: 'create initial xml'
          inputs:
            rootDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/policy'
            targetFiles: initial_policy.xml
            tokenPrefix: '${'
            tokenSuffix: '}$'
            enableTelemetry: false
          continueOnError: true

        - bash: |      
           api=test-policy
           accessTokenResponse=$(az account get-access-token --resource=https://management.core.windows.net/);
           #echo "The token response is $accessTokenResponse"
           accessToken=$(echo $accessTokenResponse | jq -j '.accessToken');
           #echo "The retrieved access token is $accessToken"
           authorizationHeader="Bearer $accessToken"
           #echo "Generated authorization header $authorizationHeader"
           authorizationHeader="Bearer $accessToken"
           #echo "Generated authorization header $authorizationHeader"
           
           curl --location 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/xxxxxx/apis/xxx-api/policies?api-version=2022-08-01&=null' \
           -H "Authorization: $authorizationHeader"   | jq ".value[0].properties.value"      
          name: Resolve_variable
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current Bash script is calling the Azure API Management REST API "[**Api Policy - List By Api**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/api-policy/list-by-api?view=rest-apimanagement-2022-08-01&tabs=HTTP)" to list the policy configuration at the API level.

In the script, after using the '[**`jq`**](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#invoking-jq)' command to parse the JSON response to get the XML content for the policy configuration, there is no subsequent operation to write the XML content into an XML file. If you run the same script by other ways, such as manually running it on your local machine, the XML file also will not be generated.

To generate the XML file using the XML content gotten from the REST API "**Api Policy - List By Api**", you can try like as below.

```bash
./apiops.sh | jq -r ".value[0].properties.value" > policy/initial_policy.xml
```

This will write the XML content into the XML file '**`initial_policy.xml`**':

- If the XML file exists, its original content will be overridden by the new content.
- If the XML file does not exist, a new one will be automatically created and then written with the content.

---

In addition, If the APIM has some existing policy configuration, as suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77857922/14697693), you also can try using the Azure PowerShell cmdlet "[**Get-AzApiManagementPolicy**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/get-azapimanagementpolicy?view=azps-11.1.0)" to get and save the configuration to an XML file, and then update the XML file using the new values passed from the parameters.

---